# How to set up my development environment with a Dart client and an adhoc server?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

When I develop (not in deployment mode)

1. My client is in Dart on workspace/foo_client
2. My server is another platform in workspace/foo_server, this platform serve static assets from workspace/foo_server/public. This platform can reload on live changing assets. I need this server as his providing data in Json to the client.

When I run my server :

- the server provide the initial page holding the client elements
- the server provide data to the client

I would like to have server and client up to date automatically

- when I change something in my client
- when I change something in my server

Is there another way to do it easily ?

It would be useful to call "pub serve --out workspace/foo_server/public" to have a nice development experience : i'm working on workspace/foo_client and it's automatically deployed by my adhoc server platform. I have created an issue : https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20432.

Comment: I still dont get the actual problem. Can you explain your actual problem more detailed? I'd say if you have two projects that you should have, than you can start each project separately. This also depends on your code.

Comment: Maybe `pub build -o workspace/foo_server/public` does what you want.

Comment: "pub build" won't compile again dart to javacript if a dart file is updated, "pub serve" would.